# Manipulate JSON object to fit it to highcharts

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, highcharts

I have a JSON response from MongoDB in this format:

```
[{
    "_id" : 4,
    "status" : [ 
        {
            "status" : "Closed",
            "count" : 2
        }, 
        {
            "status" : "Open",
            "count" : 17
        }
    ],
    "count" : 19
},
{
    "_id" : 3,
    "status" : [ 
        {
            "status" : "Closed",
            "count" : 6
        }, 
        {
            "status" : "Open",
            "count" : 22
        }
    ],
    "count" : 28
}]
```

I want to manipulate this into an array of objects so it becomes easy for me to pass them onto the highcharts.

```
categories: ['3', '4']

series: [{
            name: 'Open',
            data: [22,17]
        }, {
            name: 'Closed',
            data: [6,2]
        }]
```

Basically I want to group all the "open" and "closed" with respect to the categories.

Comment: You can loop through the array and create the required structures

Comment: Can you explain the mapping more between input and output? I don't understand how you derive your output.

Comment: How you are getting the values for data array?

Comment: Why do you want to group them like that?

Comment: I want to group them like that so it becomes easy to plot the graph in highcharts. So the first element in both data arrays (22, 6) belongs to category 3 and the next one (17,2) belongs to category 4 and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your data is always formatted like this i would do something like this:

```js
var data = [{
    "_id" : 4,
    "status" : [ 
        {
            "status" : "Closed",
            "count" : 2
        }, 
        {
            "status" : "Open",
            "count" : 17
        }
    ],
    "count" : 19
},
{
    "_id" : 3,
    "status" : [ 
        {
            "status" : "Closed",
            "count" : 6
        }, 
        {
            "status" : "Open",
            "count" : 22
        }
    ],
    "count" : 28
}]

$(function () {
        var myCategories = [];
        var mySeries = [{
                        name: 'Open',
                        data: []
                        },{
                        name: 'Closed',
                        data: []
                     }];
    
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
         myCategories.push(data[i]._id);
         mySeries[0].data.push(data[i].status[0].count);
         mySeries[1].data.push(data[i].status[1].count);
    }
  $('#series').text(JSON.stringify(mySeries));
    $('#categories').text(JSON.stringify(myCategories));
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Categories:</label>
<div id="categories"></div>
<label>Series:</label>
<div id="series"></div>
```

Then in highcharts, simply set

```
categories: myCategories,
series: mySeries
```